# Algorithm Step Count Analysis - Homework

Tags: algorithm

Got a question on this step count problem. I think I have the basic idea but struggling to get the math straight on paper. First the pseudo code:

```
for i = 1 to n
    x = x + 1
    j = n
    while (j>1)
        j = j/2
```

and my interpretation:

n/2 + 1

n/2

n/2

n/2   <-- top part of summation for line 4 (the while loop)

Σ   logn+2

i=1   <-- bottom part of summation for line 4 (the while loop)

n/2   <-- top part of summation for line 5 (body of the while loop)

Σ   logn+1

i=1   <-- bottom part of summation for line 5 (body of the while loop)

---

So the first three lines in step count aren't bad to see, but then the two summations inside the loop are a bit tricky to me. So for the first one logn + 2 I can split into two steps:

n/2

Σ   2

i=1

and

n/2

Σ   logn

i=1

so I'm used to dealing with straight summation of n, not n/2. But I'll give it a quick shot.

2*((n^2+n)/2) or rather just drop the fraction for this one so it's straight: n^2+n.

Then for the logn piece:

logn*((n^2+n)/2) = ? Now I'm not really sure here. Not sure this even simplifies down at all. If anyone has any suggestions on this I'd appreciate it, but I think what I got there is it for this half. So I combine the two together to get my final answer for the first summation line 4 of the pseudo code:

logn * (n^2+n)/2 + n^2 + n

And for the second summation I think it would then be:

logn * n^2 + n

(can borrow a bit from what I had already completed above. Just dropped the part where I had 2 * (n^2+n)/2 and instead I'll simply have two sets of the half which combine to make one n^2+n if that makes any sense I think?

Please let me know if I've totally lost it. Thank you!!

Comment: You have code, but not what the question is asking...? What are we supposed to help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're analysis is a bit off. First, notice that what happens in the body of the `for` loop is independent of the value of `i` or `x`. So the `for` loop executes `n` times and the same number of steps happen in the `for` loop body each time. The body of the `while` loop executes floor(log<sub>2</sub>(n)) times. That's about all the analysis that's needed. The result is n*floor(log<sub>2</sub>(n)). (If by "step" you mean statement executions, you need to modify this a bit to account for the number of statements in each loop body.)

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for the reply. The nlogn then is a simplified version though. Is the long hand n(n+1)/2 * logn + 2  for the while loop statement as it will occur summation of n times log of n + 2? then the body of the while loop will execute just one less time so same thing but + 1?

Comment: I think the long hand is + 2 as if n = 4 then loop runs check j = 4. Loop runs check j = 2, loop runs check j = 1 and stops.  oops.. it's logn + 1 for the while loop check and the body only executes twice

Comment: ok, so body of the while loop will be just summation n(n+1) / 2 * logn. cool, I think thats it. What are your thoughts Ted? They don't want short hand in this case

Comment: oh and I get what you said about n in the first several lines, I had it wrong. Not n/2, just n. so line 1 is n+1, lines 2 and 3 are just n then

Comment: @JKK - Note that log_2(4) = 2 and when n==4 (through 7), the `while` loop executes twice for each iteration of the outer loop. So floor(log_2(n)) is the right count. The outer loop just does this `n` times. There's no n(n+1) factor. It's just n*floor(log_2(n)).